# Simple if in .bat or .cmd to check if booted in safe mode or not

Tags: batch-file, safe-mode

OS: Win 7
I googled a lot and I found one answer here which not helping me as it outputs just the answer (I cannot used it in IF statement

I have also found this

```
if  /i  "%SAFEBOOT_OPTION%"=="MINIMAL" echo We're in Safe Mode!
```

I have tried it almost 10 times and the SAFEBOOT_OPTION variable is always empty.

Comment: Show us the answer you found here - maybe it **can** be used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%SAFEBOOT_OPTION%` variable only exists if you are currently booted into `safe mode` (contains `MINIMAL`) or `safe mode with networking` (contains `NETWORK`).

From [Microsoft's Docs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315222/en-us):

> An environment variable is set when you use one of the Safe Boot options. The environment variable is SAFEBOOT_OPTION. This variable is set to either Network or to Minimal.

**EDIT**

Just tested the script below while running in safe mode:

```
@echo off
if /i "%SAFEBOOT_OPTION%"=="MINIMAL" echo We're in Safe Mode!
```

This script printed `We're in Safe Mode!` to cmd as expected.

Comment: Two minor problems here. First, as you say, ** This variable is set to either Network or to Minimal.** which means that the test should be `if defined safeboot_option echo We're in safe mode! (%safeboot_option%)` Second problem is that if `safeboot_option` is **NOT** set, your posted statement would generate a syntax error - you'd need to `"quote"` the operands (or otherwise ensure they're not empty such as `...Q%SAFEBOOT_OPTION%==QMINIMAL...`

Comment: @Magoo You make an excellent point about quoting the operands (which I neglected to do). This has been rectified with an edit. This also resolves the case where `%SAFEBOOT_OPTION%` is undefined, as it will now evaluate to `""`, which will not match `MINIMAL`. This could be changed to `if defined`, if you wanted to detect both `safe mode` and `safe mode with networking`. I used a comparison with `MINIMAL` to more closely resemble the code posted by user3058737.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a command which outputs the mode, then you can use it in a `IF`.

For eg. the command is `MyCommand` which outputs "You are in safe mode" if you booted in safe mode, then you can use the following

```
@echo off
MyCommand | findstr /c:"You are in safe mode" > nul
if errorlevel 1 goto NotSafe

echo Safe
REM Do whatever you want in Safe Mode
goto end

:NotSafe
echo NotSafe
REM Do whatever you want in Safe Mode
:end
```

If you want to check for a single word instead of a space separated string you do not need the `/c:` in `findstr`. You can just use `findstr SafeMode`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Everyone I know the thread is a bit old. However I recently ran into an issue with a batch i did not want technicians to run in safe mode. However I wasnt really able to find an answer. Using the above however I was able to peruse the rest of the web and finally came up with a check that can be done when you want other work done as well. So in this case if it detects safe mode it will goto **:safemode** and quit. or continue the job.

```
wmic COMPUTERSYSTEM GET BootupState | findstr /i "fail-safe" > nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto safemode
```

//stuff

```
:safemode
    cls
    Echo.
    Echo Halting system is in SAFEMODE!!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to detect if the system is in normal mode or safe mode, try this using batch program, try this simple:

> @echo off
>
> if "%SAFEBOOT_OPTION%"=="" goto normal
>
> echo This computer is in safe mode!
>
> goto ext
>
> :normal
>
> echo This computer is running in normal mode!
>
> goto ext
>
> :ext
>
> pause
>
> exit

If the SAFEBOOT_OPTION variable is empty, then the system is in normal mode.